# iAds saying it is covered up

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In the output window, when I bring up an menu (subview) over the current view, but NOT covering the iAd... I also, just to be sure, Did a BringSubviewToFront (iAds);

However, it still issues the message in the output.

Worse, if I touch on the ad it won't activate it.  I'm pretty sure this would result in not only my app getting rejected, but also in making zero from ads...

I have several different views that I pop up in this fashion, one of them seems to not have the problem...  However, I haven't figured out any differences between them...

-Chert

Comment: Without some code / the view hierarchy it will be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some old code that created a controller for that view (now a sub-view), and It appears that it was getting confused with a view having a subview that is registered to another controller from the controller that it is registered in... Can't say that I blame it for getting confused!   -Chert